# How do I do the maths for starting a bitcoin mining startup in Kuwait?

Tags: mining-profitability

Kuwait has the world's cheapest electricity which makes it a good choice for bitcoin miners. I am talking to a businessman in Kuwait who is interested in helping me move to Kuwait from Pakistan and provide me with the required hardware if I am able to convince him it would make a good profit.

I am looking for the details of all the costs involved in starting a bitcoin mining startup and its costs in Kuwait.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many bitcoin mining profitability calculators all over the web:

- http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/
- https://mining-profit.com/calculator
- http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/bitcoin-mining-calculator

You would have to get your hands on some hardware, which can be quite expensive indeed. The only advantage you have is the recurring electricity cost, but note that the hardware is not cheap and often takes many months to make profitable. You'll need a good contact at BitMain or some other ASIC manufacturer so you can get your hands on the latest hardware early so you can mine them for the longest time.

Best of luck!